# Sharepoint Task assign more than one person

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a task list in sharepoint, i have to assign this task to more than one person. The flow should be the one first person finished the task it should go to the other person for completion. Is there a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In case of OOTB workflow, use the **"One at a time(Serial)"** option from approvers.

[image]

Similarly, in case of SharePoint Designer workflows, its the same -

[image]

Comment: I am taking users' email ids' from Person or Group filed which is multiple value allowed. When I am fetching the values from that field in SharePoint 2013 designer, it is not taking the values in the same order/sequence.  Do you know why ?

Comment: Did you try sorting the names/email adresses manually? Please elaborate how did you set the email addresses. If this post solved your actual query, please mark it as answer!

Comment: I am taking the users from a multi value Person or Group field. While I am fetching that field in SPD, it is automatically sorting users with their userI D instead of the sequence I have given in the column.